# White space next to div despite margin-left set to 0

Tags: html, css

Can anybody help me understand why there is a white gap to the left of my div, 'header-image'? I am making a website, and have a div at the top, but when I open it in an editor, it shows a small white gap to the left of the div next to the page. I don't have a margin-left or a padding-left.
Here is a snippet: https://jsfiddle.net/ahpon8wu/2/

```
<body>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="js\maincontent.js"></script>
<script src = 'js\main.js'></script>
<div class = "menu">
<ul>
    <li id = "active"><a>Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="politics.html">Articles</a></li>
    <li><a href="members.html">Members</a></li>
    <li><a href="discussions.html">Discussions</a></li>
    <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>

</ul>
</div>



<div class="header-image">
<div class="titlecontainer">
    <div class = "header-title">
        <h1> Anarchists and Autocrats </h1>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

here is the css:

```
.menu {
width: 100%;
background-color: #ffffff;
height: 100px;
position: fixed;
top: 0;
left: 0;
z-index: 4;
font-family: NexaLight;
text-align:center;
width:100%;
overflow:hidden;
box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35);

}


.menu ul {
display: inline-block;
vertical-align:middle;
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
line-height: 100px;

}

.menu li {
padding-left: 40px;
padding-right: 40px;
display:inline;
text-decoration:none;
list-style:none;
vertical-align:middle;

}

.menu li a {
text-decoration:none;
list-style:none;
color: #333333;
text-shadow: 2px 2px rgb(112, 112, 112, 0.3);

}


.menu li a:hover {
color: #4769b2;
text-shadow: 2px 2px rgb(108, 138, 204, 0.3);
}



.header-title {
text-align: center;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;


}

.titlecontainer {
width: 100%;
position: fixed;
z-index: 0;


}

.header-title h1 {
color: white;
text-shadow: 2px 2px 4px #d1d1d1;
font-family:'NexaLight';
letter-spacing: 1px;
white-space: nowrap;
text-transform: uppercase;
font-size: 3em;
text-align: center;

}

.header-image {
background: url("images/Westminster.jpg") bottom/ cover;
width: 100%;
height: 65vh;
background-size: cover;
background-attachment: fixed;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
position: relative;
margin-top: 90px; /*Somehow, this means that the 'header-image' div will 
slot right beneath the bar instead of going underneath? */
/* Here I use something from www.howtocenterincss.com */
display: flex;
justify-content: center; /*Not sure if this is neccessary */
align-items: center;
z-index: -1;
margin-bottom: 10px;

}

@media (orientation: portrait) {
.header-image {
    background: url("images/Westminstermobile.jpg") bottom/ cover;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 50vh;
    background-size: cover;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    position: relative;
}

p {
    overflow-y: hidden;
}

html, body {
    overflow-x: scroll;

}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to the browser default margins on the tags `html`, `body`, please add the below css at the top of your stylesheet/styles and correct the issue!!

```
html, body{
    margin:0px;
}
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(window).scroll(function(event) {
    let scroll = $(this).scrollTop();
    let opacity = 1 - (scroll / 200);
    if (opacity >= 0) {
      $('.header-title').css('opacity', opacity);
      if (scroll / 200 >= 0.9) {
        $('.header-title').hide();
      } else {
        $('.header-title').show();
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0px;
}

body {
  font-family: Futura, sans-serif;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: SourceSansPro-Regular;
  src: url('fonts/SourceSansPro-Regular.ttf');
}

@font-face {
  font-family: SourceSansPro-Light src: url('fonts/SourceSansPro-Light.ttf');
}

@font-face {
  font-family: NexaLight;
  src: url('fonts/Nexa-Light.otf');
}

html,
body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.menu {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  height: 100px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 4;
  font-family: NexaLight;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35);
}

.menu ul {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  line-height: 100px;
}

.menu li {
  padding-left: 40px;
  padding-right: 40px;
  display: inline;
  text-decoration: none;
  list-style: none;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.menu li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  list-style: none;
  color: #333333;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px rgb(112, 112, 112, 0.3);
}

.menu li a:hover {
  color: #4769b2;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px rgb(108, 138, 204, 0.3);
}

#active {
  font-weight: bold;
}


/* Fonts!!!
font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
font-family: 'Arima Madurai', cursive;


*/

.header-title {
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.titlecontainer {
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 0;
}

.header-title h1 {
  color: white;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px 4px #d1d1d1;
  font-family: 'NexaLight';
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 3em;
  text-align: center;
}

.header-image {
  background: url("http://www.freeimageslive.com/galleries/buildings/london/pics/palace_of_westminster.jpg") bottom/ cover;
  width: 100%;
  height: 65vh;
  background-size: cover;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 90px;
  /*Somehow, this means that the 'header-image' div will slot right beneath the bar instead of going underneath? */
  /* Here I use something from www.howtocenterincss.com */
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  /*Not sure if this is neccessary */
  align-items: center;
  z-index: -1;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

@media (orientation: portrait) {
  .header-image {
    background: url("images/Westminstermobile.jpg") bottom/ cover;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 50vh;
    background-size: cover;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    position: relative;
  }
  p {
    overflow-y: hidden;
  }
  html,
  body {
    overflow-x: scroll;
  }
}

.contentwrapper {
  width: 75%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.content {
  height: 1500px;
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
  font-family: 'SourceSansPro-Regular';
  z-index: 1;
  font-size: 105%;
  text-indent: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  overflow-x: auto;
  margin-left: 0px;
  margin-right: 0px;
}

#Subtitle {
  text-align: center;
}

#firstpoint,
#secondpoint,
#thirdpoint {
  padding-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<link href="main.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
<!-- Google fonts beneath -->
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Arima+Madurai:300|Lato:300|Open+Sans:300|Quicksand|Raleway" rel="stylesheet">

<head>
  <title> Big Oof </title>


</head>

<body>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js\maincontent.js"></script>
  <script src='js\main.js'></script>
  <div class="menu">
    <ul>
      <li id="active"><a>Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="politics.html">Articles</a></li>
      <li><a href="members.html">Members</a></li>
      <li><a href="discussions.html">Discussions</a></li>
      <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>

    </ul>
  </div>



  <div class="header-image">
    <div class="titlecontainer">
      <div class="header-title">
        <h1> Anarchists and Autocrats </h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="contentwrapper">
    <div class="content">


      <div id="firstpoint">
        <p>Anarchists and Autocrats is a webzine/blog which was founded in 2018. Since then, Anarchists and Autocrats has become host to over twenty authors, artists and thinkers who write about current events, philosophy, politics, culture and many other
          topics.
        </p>
      </div>





      <div id="secondpoint">
        <p> While all authors try to produce well-balanced views within articles and essays written, it goes without needing to be said that each author has their own biasses that will find themselves within each article, whether that's in the language used
          or even the subject matter. Anarchists and Autocrats aims to bring about different and far-reaching opinions, but it is impossible to present a fully diverse and differing set of viewpoints for which we can present: finding an anarcho-syndicalist,
          a monarchist, a paleo-conservative and a social democrat all at once for instance will be difficult, or even impossible; ultimately, although different viewpoints are supported and promoted, Anarchists and Autocrats will have difficulty presenting
          a completely diverse and varying set of viewpoints. Anarchists and Autocrats also does not necessarily support the viewpoints that individual authors hold.
        </p>
      </div>
      <div id="thirdpoint">

        <p> Anarchists and Autocrats is an open project for everyone still in secondary education, so if you would like to get in touch or write an article, please navigate to the 'contact' tab. </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, that helped me and it worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

As Nauren said, the problem is solved if you add

```
    html, body{
      margin:0px;
    }
```

Better yet, use a CSS reset stylesheet. Browsers have different styles by default, so what this does is reset the styling of all HTML elements to a homogenous base. That way, you can start styling for every browser without worrying about inconsistencies between them.

This article can get you started https://cssreset.com/what-is-a-css-reset/

Comment: Thank you very much! I have read that and it is very useful. Thanks!